# *Getting on one's nerves*, *last nerve* or *third nerve*?

Tags: phrases, idioms

I'm quite familiar with the idiomatic phrase of *getting on one's nerves*, but less so with *getting on one's last nerve*, though I had a friend who used a variation: *getting on one's third nerve*.  Is one version preferred over the other in different locations? Is *third nerve* used anywhere?

Comment: Before we start seeing NGrams and Google hit counts, let me point out in advance that there is a malady known as [third nerve palsy](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1198462-overview), which will nullify any of those search strategies.

Comment: @Robusto I didn't know that, but it could be why my friend used the term if she was familiar with the malady.

Comment: @Robusto - I had never heard of that malady (or, rather, I've certainly seen it but never knew its name.)  I'd also never heard the phrase "you're getting on my third nerve," but I believe I might start using it - the image of going literally cross-eyed with frustration is irresistible.  (My apologies to any actual sufferers of the malady, as no offense is intended.)

Comment: @Robusto, actually you are not right - http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=getting+on+my+last+nerve%2Cgetting+on+my+third+nerve%2Cgetting+on+my+nerves&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3 , but only because third nerve yields no hits (in this form) ;)

Comment: @MT_Head, I believe my friend made up *getting on my third nerve*.  I'm sure she wouldn't mind you putting the phrase  into circulation.  :)

Comment: I always thought it's getting on one's
nerves... But then getting on on one's last
nerve makes perfect sense and is much
better. I guess I just learnt something
new. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a small difference in meaning, as
"last nerve" is a bit stronger than just "nerves".

> Getting on one's nerves

Indicates that the person is strongly annoyed by someone/something.

> Getting on one's last nerve

Indicates that the person has been so annoyed (maybe over a period of time) that he is on the edge to snap.

> Getting on one's third nerve

This is one I have not heard before, but I think this is well answered in the comments already posted to the question (initiated by [@Robusto](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2303/robusto) with his reference to [third nerve palsy](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1198462-overview)).

Comment: I can't accept a comment as the answer,  so linking the comments in your answer works.

Answer (score 0):

The "third track" refers to the live electric track on the subway tracks.  As in "don't touch the third track".  I think that is another connection to referring to the "third nerve" - it's the one that has an unwelcome consequence.